# Entity body should be a correctly nested resource attribute name/value pair

Tags: php, curl, box-api

I am a beginner using PHP cURL, and am trying to make use of the Box.com API 2.0, which uses oAuth.
I am trying to return basic information about the user. Here is my code:

```
$box_1 = curl_init("https://api.box.com/2.0/users/me");
curl_setopt($box_1, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, "Authorization: Bearer token_was_here");
curl_setopt($box_1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt ($box_1, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "fields=id,name,login");
$box_curl1 = curl_exec($box_1);
curl_close($box_1);
```

When I run this, I get this error: `{"type":"error","status":400,"code":"bad_request","context_info":{"errors":[{"reason":"invalid_parameter","name":"entity-body","message":"Invalid value 'fields=id,name,login'. Entity body should be a correctly nested resource attribute name\/value pair"}]},"help_url":"http:\/\/developers.box.com\/docs\/#errors","message":"Bad Request","request_id":"request_id_was_here"}`

When I remove the 4th line, I get no response at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured it out!

**My "access token" had expired**, and since I was not choosing to output the headers, I never found this out!

I also slightly modified my code to this:

```
$token = "token here";
$box_1 = curl_init();
curl_setopt($box_1, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.box.com/2.0/users/me?fields=id");
curl_setopt($box_1, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Authorization: Bearer ".$token));
curl_setopt($box_1, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, TRUE);
curl_setopt($box_1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$box_curl1 = curl_exec($box_1);
curl_close($box_1);
```

Comment: I'm glad you're out of the woods, but this was not the cause of your original problem.  If your access token had been expired when you made that first request, you would have gotten a 401 Unauthorized response, not a 400 Bad Request.

Comment: Yes, I had also originally forgotten to change it to a GET request :)

Comment: Excellent!  That makes sense now. :D

Answer (score 1):

The `fields=id,name,login` should be in the query string, not the request body.

Comment: I tried adding it like so `$box_1 = curl_init("https://api.box.com/2.0/users/me?fields=id");`, but it makes no difference.

Comment: Yes, I added this: `curl_setopt($box_1, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, TRUE);`

Comment: Can you provide an HTTP trace of what's going over the wire?  If you're on Windows, [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) is a good tool for this.